# How to extract the Videostream without audio from MP4?

Tags: ffmpeg

how to xtract the Videostram from an MP4file with ffmpeg?
I was lookig but did´nt find anything. All i founded was m4v to mp4 not otherwise.

best regards

Comment: Mkv and mp4 are container formats so anything you find for mkv should also work for mp4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an audio track from an mp4 video file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/how-to-remove-an-audio-track-from-an-mp4-video-file).

Comment: Yes schrodigerscatcuriosity, great   Thanks